# Triggers, #instances in Z3

Tags: triggers, z3

My problem comes from a [large Boogie file](https://github.com/thanhhai1302/ftda_boogie/blob/master/paxos1.bpl). I'll just explain the relevant parts here.

I declare a new type `Msg` for messages which have 7 fields `tID, stype, bal, acc, mbal, mval, val`. These fields are declared as functions in Boogie. Then I declared 72 Msg constants `M1, ..., M72` and corresponding values of their fields. You can see the following example:

```
type Msg;
const unique M1: Msg;

function tID (Msg) returns (int);
function stype (Msg) returns (Str);
function bal (Msg) returns (int);
function acc (Msg) returns (Proc);
function mbal (Msg) returns (int);
function mval (Msg) returns (Val);
function val (Msg) returns (Val);

axiom (tID (M1) == 1);
axiom (stype (M1) == s1a);
axiom (bal (M1) == 1);
axiom (acc (M1) == ProcNull);
axiom (mbal (M1) == -2);
axiom (mval (M1) == ValNull);
axiom (val (M1) == ValNull);
```

where `Proc, Str` are some types and `s1a, ProcNull, ValNull` are some constants. Then I declare an axiom which says that two messages `m1, m2` are equal if and only if every field of `m1, m2`. This axiom uses a trigger `MsgComp(m1, m2)`.

```
function MsgComp(m1, m2: Msg): bool { true }
axiom (forall m1, m2: Msg :: {MsgComp(m1, m2)} 
    m1 == m2 <==> 
    (tID(m1) == tID(m2) && stype(m1) == stype(m2) && 
     acc(m1) == acc(m2) && bal(m1) == bal(m2) && 
     mbal(m1) == mbal(m2) && mval(m1) == mval(m2) && 
     val(m1) == val(m2)));
```

Then, I declare a new variable `m` and assign arbitrary values to its fields such that  `m` equals `M1` or `M2`. I don't say explicitly `m == M1 || m == M2`but we can prove this assertion (line 786)  with the above axiom.

```
assert (MsgComp(cMsg, M1) && MsgComp(cMsg, M2) && (cMsg == M1 || cMsg == M2));
```

However, if I want to check whether `m` is one of `M1, ..., M72`, Boogie shows that the corresponding assertion might not hold.

```
assert (MsgComp(cMsg, M1) && ... && MsgComp(cMsg, M72) && (cMsg == M1 || ...  || cMsg == M72));
```

And I found that if I check that assertion with at most 32 constants, Boogie can verify it. Why can't Boogie or Z3 verify it with more constants?

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, the check does not succeed even for the case of two constants.

I was able to get both checks to pass by changing them to the following form

```
 assert MsgComp(cMsg, M1) && MsgComp(cMsg, M2) ==> (cMsg == M1 || cMsg == M2);
```

(Notice that the `&&` in the middle has been changed to `==>`.)

This also works for the assertion with the 72 values.

I don't know why this change matters. It looks like the conjuncts are ignored or simplified away before triggering happens.

Comment: AFAIK, SMTLib conjunctions are not short-circuiting and could therefore be handled in parallel. That would explain why the triggers `MsgComp(...)` aren't necessarily available in the original encoding, but are in yours.